# Как TeamViewer "обходит" UAC на Win7?

Tags: java, c#, .net, windows, uac

Не все знают, но в TeamViewer есть возможность удаленного подклдючения под админом. Если при запуске TeamViewer тех. специалист выберет авторизацию через учетную запись Windows, введет логин и пароль администратора для удаленного компьютера, то на стороне сотрудника появится запрос на подтверждение прав приложения. Самое удобное в этом подходе то, что сотрудник не вводит пароль администратора и не знает его, а только нажимает Да. Далее TeamViewer на стороне сотрудника перезапускается и работает уже с правами администратора.

Мне нужно реализовать нечто подобное, есть много компьютеров с одинаковыми паролями, нужно программно их удаленно модифицировать. Пока получилось только через psexec получить доступ администратора, но работает это только с выключенным UAC, а выключить его я, естественно, не могу (UAC мне этого не позволит).

Вариант с запросом разрешения без ввода пароля меня тоже бы устроил, но не понятно как именно разработчики TeamViewer так сделали.

Comment: Если TW запущен не как сервис, а как приложение - шиш ты заадминишься.

Comment: https://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerQS.exe запускается изначально как приложение? Он не требует ничего при старте.

Comment: Парол попадает с удаленной машины. А далее случается какая-то магия, вводится пароль, и далее в какой-то момент запрашивается подтверждение пользоватля в виде кнопочек Да/Нет.

Comment: TeamViewer работает с правами админа, а не учетка меняется. Если надо зайти под админом можно перегазрузиться через TeamViewer, но это уже отдельная тема. Даже без перезагрузки в этом состоянии можно уже нажать "Запуск с правами администратора" и экран ввода пароля будет виден, т.е. можно самому ввести пароль. При этом в менеджере задач видно, что TeamViewer уже выполняется от имени пользователя под которым подключились, т.е под админом. А фаловый менеджер TeamViewer получает доступ к файлам админа.

Comment: *TeamViewer работает с правами админа* Вы стартуете приложение от имени пользователя, а оно, не имея установленных компонентов с адм. привилегиями (сервиса), работает с правами админа? Вы это серьёзно?

Comment: Предлагаю в целях избежания флуда писать более конструктивную информацию. Участие в обсуждении предполагает предварительное подробное знакомство с описанным функционалом TeamViewer. Если у вас что-то не работает или работает не так, как я описал, пишите обоснованные ответы.

Comment: И еще раз про админ права, приложение перезапускает себя с админ правами после получения с удаленного компьютера логина и пароля учетки с правами админа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е. я так понимаю здесь есть 2 стороны: сотрудник и администратор.
Администратор желает, чтобы TV сотрудника работал от имени админа того компьютера, а сотрудник как бы не прочь.

В чём сложность тогда - я не вижу. Логин и пароль администраторской учётки просто передаются на удалённый компьютер, где TV запрашивает у сотрудника разрешение. Далее TV сам себя запустит от имени администратора (ведь программу можно запустить от имени пользователя зная логин и пароль https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx).

Вот и всё...

Comment: Когда не имеешь дело с разработкой под Windows, это не так очевидно. Я пробовал команду runas и утилиту psexec, но первая не принимала пароль через консоль, вторая не работает с включенным UAC, и я начал сомневаться, что UAC вообще позволяет запускать что-то от администратора без ввода пароля. Ваш ответ дал ключевые слова и позволил найти другое решение.

Comment: Ну хоть этим помог. Мне кажется, почти под любой платформой есть эта возможность. Это вопрос второй таки. Если как следует по искать, то решение можно найти.

Comment: Я и нашел, но первая партия вызвала сомнения. Если как следует искать, то stackowerflow бы не существовал. Экономия времени.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добиться такого же результата как в случае с TeamViewer, можно воспользоваться двумя утилитам:

```
miniRunAs.exe Login Password Elevate.exe "C:\MyApp.exe"
```

---

**miniRunAs** - Запуск от имени другого пользователя с паролем из консоли.

http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/c/1.htm

---

**Elevate** - Вывод запроса на повышение прав. Если Elevate.exe уже запущена под админом, то пароль не требуется, если нет - запрашивается еще и пароль.

http://www.winability.com/elevate/